# Use of char* in C++ for strings

Tags: c++, string, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   char *a;
   cin>>a;
   cout<<a;/*when input is string it gives segmentation fault*/
   char* b="hello";/*while this thing works fine*/
   cout<<b;
}
```

What is the difference between two exactly?

Comment: `cin >> a` is incorrect.

Comment: the difference is the first is incorrect

Comment: You need to allocate memory: `char *a = new char[20];`

Comment: The difference is that you didn't read your C++ book yet.

Comment: The second only works fine because your compiler is out of date. The conversion from a string literal to `char*` is now forbidden, so that should be `char const *b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless explicitly initialized, local variables are not initialized in any way, their values is *indeterminate* (and in reality will be seemingly random). That means your pointer `a` will most likely not point to a valid location, so when you use it to get input, the program will write to some memory it does not own, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (which is just about the most common cause of crashes).

When you define the variable `b` you tell the compiler that is should be pointing to a specific place, to an array of characters created by the compiler and owned by the program. You *initialize* the variable, so using it will work fin. However, note that string literals are arrays of characters that are considered *read-only*, so to be correct you should really do e.g.

```
const char* b = "hello";
```

Answer (score 2):

in the second example there is memory allocated by the compiler is a special place for the string literal, in the first example there is no such space...

also since `cin` doesn't limit the amount of input you take in you shouldn't use it to fill a naked `char *` buffer, unless you do limit the input to less than the buffer

but you could in theory do something like (I think... if the stream overrides work like that):

```
char *a = (char *)malloc(500);
cin >> setw(500) >> a;
```

Comment: Why would you ever use `malloc()` for this in C++?

Comment: because I am an awesome C programmer and a horrible c++ programmer :)

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S you have to cast the return of malloc in c++, just not in C, and I have read that answer many times and don't agree with it in principle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space to store the characters, in the

```
cin >> a;
```

you are storing them to an invalid location, since the `a` `char` pointer, is not pointing to valid memory yet, so you need to make it point to a valid block which

1. You can request by means of the `new` operator like this

   ```
   a = new char[length];
   cin >> a;
   ```

   but you need to be careful to do

   ```
   delete[] a;
   ```

   when you have finished using it, and also be careful not to write more than `length - 1` bytes to it.
2. Declare it as an array like

   ```
   char a[100];
   cin >> a;
   ```

   will be valid then.

But you should avoid that in c++ and use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *a;// it is pointer which is memory was unallocated.
```

So using this you cannot able to get the value for that. You have to allocate the memory for that dynamically.

```
char *b="hello";
```

`"hello"` will be stored in the read only memory. So `cout`  simply print that content.

Comment: It should be `const char* b = "hello"`. The code you reproduce has been illegal C++ for some years, deprecated for a decade before that, unsafe since the inception of C.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared a pointer, but you haven't set aside any memory to store the string itself.  In your code, `a` hasn't been initialized to point anywhere meaningful.  You either need to set it to point to an existing buffer:

```
char buf[SOME_SIZE];
char *a = buf;
```

or you need to allocate that memory at runtime:

```
char *a = new char[SOME_SIZE];
```

The reason

```
char *b = "hello";
```

works is that space has been set aside to store the string literal `"hello"`, and the address of that string is assigned to `b`.  Note that attempting to update the contents of a string literal will invoke undefined behavior (at least in C, and I'm reasonably sure it's true in C++), so you don't want to write something like

```
cin >> b;
```

as long as `b` points to the literal.

Comment: _"and I'm reasonably sure it's true in C++"_ It used to be. But then the conversion was deprecated and finally outright banned. `char* b = "hello"` is simply illegal in C++ now.

Answer (score 0):

Both constructs are wrong. This first is wrong in the effect that it specifies, but if that were the only problem with the code the compiler would have to oblige you and create an executable with that ungood effect. The second construct is wrong in that it breaks the rules of the C++ language, so a conforming compiler will not accept it.

---

The first construct:

```
char *a;
cin>>a;
```

uses an uninitialized pointer variable `a`. This causes **Undefined Behavior**, where the program may crash, or send angry e-mails to the Swizz president, or do what you thought it would do, whatever. The compiler is obliged to produce an executable, but may issue warning diagnostics.

---

The second construct:

```
char* b="hello";
```

is **invalid** in standard C++. Standard C++ provides no conversion from string literal to `char*`. Some compilers may however still accept it, then initializing `b` to a pointer to the first character in the string `"hello"`.

---

Instead of dealing with raw pointers and such you should use `std::string`, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    string a;
    getline( cin, a );
    cout << a << "\n";
    string const b="hello";
    cout << b << "\n";
}
```